Why does inverter malfunctions when PCB is placed near metal enclosure?
I have designed a three phase inverter to drive a Synchronous motor. The motor operates fine when I place the PCB outside of the Aluminum enclosure of the motor. The voltage and frequency increases linearly during startup. The DC supply is 56-72 volt and it is converted to three phase AC. Problem arises only when a metal sheet is placed  under it (specifically under MOSFET terminal). There is 1.6 mm insulation between PCB and metal casing / any other sheet. The problem don’t show up if insulation is 10 mm. I have attached a picture of PCB and casing. 


Overheating issue? Looks like the "insulation" is just paper which is a poor thermal conductor.

You should post a schematic and a diagram that shows where the aluminium sheet is placed relative to the PCB. You should also explain whether the aluminium sheet was ground or connected to something or floating. Is the aluminium sheet representing the motor housing as a convenient method of demonstrating the problem?

Problem causes when the conductors are in floating state. If it is grounded, problem does not occur. However I was thinking connecting motor body directly to DC ground terminal may not be a good idea. @Andyaka

@TomCarpenter I also checked with 1.6 mm plastic.  The MOSFET drain to source resistance is 9 mOhms. So It's not much hot. And PCB is 2 OZ and traces are 16 mm in width. Both top an bottom layer is carrying power.

PCB malfunctions within 2-3 seconds if metal is placed under it (within 10 mm approximately)

What is the problem (is it the failed component which seems to be a resistor located next to R26)?  Why was R10 not loaded?  Where is the schematic?  Please post a photo of how the system is physically arranged when the problem happens as per your comment: "Problem arises only when a when a metal sheet is placed under it".

@FabioBarone the resistors are for measuring current. It's not the problem. Problem is the motor stalls if PCB is placed near metal. I can add schematic of the bridge circuit.

So what is that on the location next to R26, is it a loop of wire?  The photo is not clear.  If it is a loop of wire, then does that mean that the current sense resistor value is now very low, only a few milli-ohms?

Question 5: is this (A) a completely new design that has never been fully tested, or (B) just one unit off the production line of a design that has been fully type-tested, and this is just one particular build that is not behaving normally?

Resistor besides R26 is short circuited to disable over current trip of MOSFET driver. Otherwise I could not see the stall condition. And this is new product. It was not fully tested before.

Question 6: Is that the complete schematic of the entire PCA?  I don't think so, there are at least two connectors on the PCA, the schematic only shows 1.  The PCA also has a quad-pack chip with at least 60 pins, this is not on the schematic.

Suggestion: your original post does not clearly describe the problem, I suggest you edit the post to state the problem more clearly.  Please include those photos I mentioned.    Question 7:  Do any fault LEDs get lit up when the fault occurs?  Does the controller report any fault messages?

Responding to your comment:

"Resistor besides R26 is short circuited to disable over current trip of MOSFET driver."

It seems that the controller chip is sensing an over-current condition.  I noticed there are no low-pass filters on the current sense circuit, refer: R10, R11, R56 and pin 9 of U2.
I suggest placing an R-C low pass filter at pin 9 of U2 to reduce the high-frequency components of the voltage at the node [V_trip].  A time-constant of about 10 micro-seconds might be a good starting point, but you will need to check that this is still fast enough to protect the MOSFETs from being damaged by a shorted output.   Also, the layout of the PCA might be causing significant "noise" to appear on the sense pins of the control chip U2.

Thanks. High frequency components increase in the current Measurement line in the presence of metal nearby and the fault pin of Mosfet driver is triggered. And motor is stalled during startup as gate driver freeze for some moments after fault.

I need to check how to reduce the noise level.
